# nginx alias in location - lost last character

Tags: nginx

I have nginx config

its part

```
location ~ ^/api/(?<module>.+)/doc/ {
    autoindex on;
    index index.html;
    alias /home/dmac/www/hub/hub/modules/RestApi/Resources/Doc/$1;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/hub-test-error.log debug;
}
```

But when i make request, i have error

2015/03/06 18:46:43 [error] 11158#0: *1 opendir()
"/home/dmac/www/hub/hub/modules/RestApi/Resources/Doc/dashboar" failed
(2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: hub.dev,
request: "GET /api/dashboard/doc/ HTTP/1.1", host: "hub.dev"

OR

2015/03/06 18:29:37 [error] 9941#0: *1 opendir() "/home/dmac/www/hub/hub/modules/RestApi/Resources/Doc/consultan" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: hub.dev, request: "GET /api/consultant/doc/ HTTP/1.1", host: "hub.dev"

I try change config

```
    location ~ ^/api/(consultant|dashboard)/doc/ {
```

but error the same.

nginx version: nginx/1.7.10
ubuntu 14.04 x64

Why i have this error? How fix it?
Do you know any oter way to configure nginx location for process different modules?

Comment: Have you tried previous version? Probably it's new bug in latest version

Comment: no, i don't try previous version. But on my home PC i have nginx 1.4.6 and i try it tomorrow. May be thi is resolve my problem. I write here my  progress

Comment: I try nginx 1.4.6. Result the same. 
But if i disable "autoindex" i have error 
_*3 directory index of "/home/dimon/www/symfony/crm.dev/src/Test/consultant" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: crm.dev, request: "GET /test/consultant/doc/ HTTP/1.1", host: "crm.dev"_

Nginx has access to this directory. If i enable "autoindex", error the same as in the question (without last character in path).

Comment: maybe you can use `root` instead of `alias`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was error in nginx version **1.7.10**

In the latest versions thi error fixed. 
So just update nginx.

Comment: Any source? Because same exists for 1.15.8.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, solved it by appending a slash to the path in the alias directive.

```
alias /home/dmac/www/hub/hub/modules/RestApi/Resources/Doc/$1/;
```

instead of

```
 alias /home/dmac/www/hub/hub/modules/RestApi/Resources/Doc/$1;
```

I'd stab a guess that some code tries to remove a trailing slash but did end up eating every last character.